# What is the use of the `prepare` argument in the createSlice function of Redix Toolkit?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I'm following the Redux tutorial from redux site, and in [Part 8](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux), when writing a reducer to handle todos they do the following:

```js
const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    //...
    todoColorSelected: {
      reducer(state, action) {
        const { color, todoId } = action.payload
        state.entities[todoId].color = color
      },
      prepare(todoId, color) {
        return {
          payload: { todoId, color }
        }
      }
    },
    //...
  }
})
```

They make use of the `prepare` function; however, I wrote that code without knowing the existence of the `prepare` function as follows (only using the `reducer`) and it works as well.

```js
const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    //...
    todoColorSelected: {
      const { color, todoId } = action.payload
      state.entities[todoId].color = color
    },
    //...
  }
})
```

So why do we need in this case the `prepare` function? or is it just a simple example where it makes no difference?

Comment: I'd recommend to check the official docs before asking on SO - it really is all explained there.

Answer (score 0):

It's a helper to run code before `action.payload` is handled by a reducer, you can transform the payload etc. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction#using-prepare-callbacks-to-customize-action-contents

Comment: Thanks but what is the difference between both snippets I posted?

Comment: Read the documentation I linked, it's explained there. You don't need `prepare` for what you did.